# Fetching Total Sale of each day and month from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with column `c_date` as `datetime`, `total` as `int` type in mysql, and i want to print out sale of each day, and total sale of each month, and total sale annually including day, month, year where there was no sale.

## Currently for daily sale, I am running below query :

```
mysql> select date(c_date) as date, sum(total) as total_sale from sale group by date;
+------------+------------+
| date       | total_sale |
+------------+------------+
| 2013-10-3  |        798 |
| 2013-10-6  |        114 |
+------------+------------+
```

## but, i want something like this :

```
mysql> select date(c_date) as date, sum(total) as total_sale from sale group by date;
+------------+------------+
| date       | total_sale |
+------------+------------+
| 2013-10-1  |          0 |
| 2013-10-2  |          0 |
| 2013-10-3  |        798 |
| 2013-10-4  |          0 |
| 2013-10-5  |          0 |
| 2013-10-6  |        114 |
+------------+------------+
```

## and for Monthly, I am getting this :

```
mysql> select c_date, month(c_date) as month, year(c_date) as year, sum(total) as total from sale group by c_date order by c_date;
+---------------------+-------+------+-------+
| c_date              | month | year | total |
+---------------------+-------+------+-------+
| 2013-10-3 02:40:06  |    10 | 2013 |   228 |
| 2013-10-3 02:41:58  |    10 | 2013 |   114 |
| 2013-10-3 02:44:36  |    10 | 2013 |   114 |
| 2013-10-3 02:46:40  |    10 | 2013 |   114 |
| 2013-10-3 02:49:15  |    10 | 2013 |   114 |
| 2013-10-3 02:53:36  |    10 | 2013 |   114 |
| 2013-10-6 07:43:27  |    10 | 2013 |   114 |
+---------------------+-------+------+-------+
```

## But i want something like this :

```
mysql> select c_date, month(c_date) as month, year(c_date) as year, sum(total) as total from sale group by c_date order by c_date;
+---------------------+-------+------+-------+
| c_date              | month | year | total |
+---------------------+-------+------+-------+
| 2013-1-3 02:40:06   |     1 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-2-3 02:41:58   |     2 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-3-3 02:44:36   |     3 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-4-3 02:46:40   |     4 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-5-3 02:49:15   |     5 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-6-3 02:53:36   |     6 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-7-6 07:43:27   |     7 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-8-3 02:44:36   |     8 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-9-3 02:46:40   |     9 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-10-3 02:49:15  |    10 | 2013 |   912 |
| 2013-11-3 02:53:36  |    11 | 2013 |     0 |
| 2013-12-6 07:43:27  |    12 | 2013 |     0 |
+---------------------+-------+------+-------+
```

Is this possible with MysqL ?

Comment: Ah, one of the interesting SQl questions. I would normally do by setting up a table of all dates and joining from it with left outer join. But curios what people will come up with.

Comment: Having separate table for each day is 1 option, but is this possible ? with out creating another table

Comment: This question doesn't have any accepted answer, if you know how to solve this add answer,
This may help to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's impossible to use *sequences* in MySQL (actually, they simply do not exist there), you'll have to create your dates range table first. That will be like:

```
CREATE TABLE dates_range (record_date DATE)
```

and then fill this table with dates, starting from minimum among dates, that exist in your `sale` table and till maximum.

After this, using SQL `LEFT JOIN` operator, you'll be able to aggregate your data like this:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(dates_range.record_date),
  MONTH(dates_range.record_date),
  DAY(dates_range.record_date),
  COALESCE(SUM(sale.total), 0) AS total_sum
FROM
  dates_range
    LEFT JOIN sale
      ON dates_range.record_date=DATE(sale.c_date)
GROUP BY
  YEAR(dates_range.record_date),
  MONTH(dates_range.record_date),
  DAY(dates_range.record_date)
```

Comment: I am getting empty result set after running your query

Comment: @JohnCargo you have to _fill your dates_range_ table. If you'll left it empty, so that will be your result

Comment: Do you mean, i need to fill the data from 0-30 days in it ?

Comment: All dates from minimum date in your `sale` table till maximum

Comment: oh god bro, this is exactly what i don't want :'(

Comment: No other way in MySQL (and I've mentioned this by pointing 'there are no sequences in MySQL'). Alternative way is to do this in your application.

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me that you need an outer join with a calendar table.

Imagine a calendar table populated like:

Calendar

```
Year Month   Day
2013 201310  2013-10-1    
2013 201310  2013-10-2
...
```

Then you can write a query like

```
         select date(c_day) as date, 
                sum(total) as total_sale 
           from calendar c 
left outer join sale s 
             on c.day = s.c_date
          where c.month = 201310
       group by c_day
         having c_day <= max(s.c_date); -- this is to avoid to show all 
                                        -- days for October
```